# Replace regex match by arbitrary function of match itself

Tags: regex, haskell

I'm trying to write a function of type `Text -> (Text -> Text) -> Text` that replaces occurrences of a regular expression in a piece of text by something else that is a function of what the regular expression has matched. There is `subRegex` from `Text.Regex` but this only allows replacing a match with some fixed replacement string whereas I would like the replacement to an an arbitrary function of the match. Is there a package that already implements something like that?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-regex-pcre-1.1.0.0/docs/Control-Lens-Regex-Text.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`matchRegexAll`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.95.2.0/docs/Text-Regex.html#v:matchRegexAll)

```
matchRegexAll
   :: Regex     -- ^ The regular expression
   -> String    -- ^ The string to match against
   -> Maybe ( String, String, String, [String] )
                -- ^ Returns: 'Nothing' if the match failed, or:
                --
                -- >  Just ( everything before match,
                -- >         portion matched,
                -- >         everything after the match,
                -- >         subexpression matches )
```

For example:

```
subFirst :: Regex -> String -> (String -> String) -> String
subFirst rx input f = case matchRegexAll rx input of
    Nothing -> input
    Just (pre, match, post, _) -> pre <> f match <> post
```

If you want to do this for all matches rather than just the first, you can call this function recursively on the remainder `post` (left as an exercise).

For a different approach, it looks like the [`text-regex-replace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-regex-replace) replace package might be of use to you.  It works directly on `Text` rather than `String`, and it appears to have the capability of arbitrary replacement functions (however the usage seems a bit obtuse).

Answer (score 0):

If you’re willing to write your pattern matching function as a parser instead of a regular expression, then the function [`Replace.Megaparsec.streamEdit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:streamEdit) with the [`match`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#v:match) combinator has the signature you’re looking for.

Here’s a [usage example in the README](https://github.com/jamesdbrock/replace-megaparsec#pattern-match-and-edit-the-matches)